# Transfer script files using ssh to my server?

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2

I'm using Amazon node `ssh` I have a `captcha.php` script on my local host. How do I transfer that to my Amazon EC2 page? I'm trying to generate a captcha. I'm using Mac terminal and installed xampp.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `scp` or `sftp`. There are also graphical tools for this on Mac.